# Minimum number of phones

Tags: c

Your are given a binary tree which contains family members. You are asked to find the total number of mobile phones that are required for the family in order to communicate under the condition that each person can share their mobile with their parent and children whereas a shared mobile can't be shared further.

```
int minPhones(struct TreeNode* root){

    //base case

    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int phones = 0;
    int shared = 2;
    int phonesNeeded(struct TreeNode* node)
    {
        if(node == NULL)
        {return 0;}
        if((node->left == NULL ||  (node->left->left == NULL && node->left->right == NULL))&& (node->right == NULL ||  (node->right->left == NULL && node->right->right == NULL)))
        {
            shared = 1;
            return 1;
        }
        if(shared == 1)
        {
            shared = 0;
            return 0;
        }
        else if(shared == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return phonesNeeded(node->left) + phonesNeeded(node->right);
    }
    phones = phonesNeeded(root) + 1;
    return phones;
}
```

This is the code I have written and would like to ask how to modify this code to the required output.

Comment: It's an unusual family if it can be represented by a binary tree, and everyone can use a mobile phone, including the deceased!

Comment: Do I understand it right that a node with a phone clears its direct parent and BOTH the direct children (if any)?

Comment: Does "a shared mobile can't be shared further" mean that each phone can be shared by at most two people?

Comment: Standard C does not support nested function definitions.

Comment: It is true that standard C doesn't support nested functions. I tried it and was working on an online compiler so I have used it, "a shared mobile cant be shared further" means that if a node has a phone then it can share with its parent node and its direct child nodes. In this family tree we will only have the people who are alive and we only consider their cases. Hope it answers all your questions.

Comment: So I think you can just count nodes at odd depth, count nodes at even depth, and use the smaller of the two counts.

Comment: But that will reduce the efficiency thus we can't get minimum because of the reason that if we put one phone in odd depths then there is a chance that a person can get 2 phones by sharing in many cases where is can be minimized. So I didn't go with that method.

Comment: @IanAbbott: No. Consider a tree with a root node whose left child roots a full subtree of 1, 2, and 4 nodes at subsequent levels and whose right child roots a subtree of 1, 2, 4, and 8 nodes. This tree has 1+4+8 nodes at even depth and 2+8 at odd depth, but giving phones to the 1 root, the 2 middle in the left subtree, and the 1 and the 4 in the right subtree is a better assignment.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But I just tried it and it worked for a few cases testing for other though, as you said that is true so will check it out thank you for mentioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a node *covered* if it has a phone or a phone is shared with it because a parent or child of it has a phone.

To cover a leaf node, either it or its parent must have a phone.

Except in a tree with only a root, there is never any advantage to assigning a phone to a leaf node because assigning a phone to its parent provides a superset of coverage:

- Assigning the phone to a leaf node covers it and its parent (unless it has none, and hence the tree is only one node) and no other nodes.
- Assigning the phone to the leaf node’s parent covers the leaf node, its parent, its grandparent (if it exists), and its sibling (if it exists).

Therefore, we should assign phones to all parents of leaves. Once that is done, we can remove from the tree all covered nodes without any uncovered children and then apply the above again: Assigning a phone to a leaf node in the remaining tree would not provide new coverage for its previous child or children, since those previous children are already covered, so the analysis of which nodes a phone provides coverage to is the same as above.

So an optimal algorithm is:

- While the tree is not empty:

  - If there is only one node, assign a phone to it and stop.
  - Assign a phone to the parent of each leaf node (only one even if it has two leaf node children).
  - Remove from the tree all covered nodes without any uncovered children.

Note that the algorithm maybe implemented, if desired, by marking nodes covered and determining leaf nodes with respect to that coverage, rather than by actually deconstructing the tree.

I think an equivalent statement of the algorithm is:

- While there is an uncovered node:

  - If there is only one node, assign a phone to it and stop.
  - Assign a phone to the parent of each node with no uncovered children.

Here is candidate prototype code I have not tested:

```
typedef struct Node { struct Node *left, *right; } Node;

void AssignPhone(Node *);

typedef enum { HavePhone, CoveredByChild, Uncovered, DoesNotExist } Coverage;


static Coverage Process(Node *p)
{
    Coverage LeftCoverage  = p->left  ? Process(p->left ) : DoesNotExist;
    Coverage RightCoverage = p->right ? Process(p->right) : DoesNotExist;
    if (LeftCoverage == Uncovered || RightCoverage == Uncovered)
    {
        AssignPhone(p);
        return HavePhone;
    }
    if (LeftCoverage == HavePhone || RightCoverage == HavePhone)
        return CoveredByChild;
    return Uncovered;
}


void ProcessRoot(Node *p)
{
    if (Process(p) == Uncovered)
        AssignPhone(p);
}
```

Comment: It is working completely fine I have modified it according to the inputs I have given and also the rest of the code thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: Please do not accept this answer, it is only a supplementary answer!**

**Eric Postpischil** posted the optimal algorithm to determine which nodes need to own a phone in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77994282/5264491).

As a supplementary answer, here is some similar code that I wrote independently based on Eric's original comment:

> @IanAbbott: No. Consider a tree with a root node whose left child roots a full subtree of 1, 2, and 4 nodes at subsequent levels and whose right child roots a subtree of 1, 2, 4, and 8 nodes. This tree has 1+4+8 nodes at even depth and 2+8 at odd depth, but giving phones to the 1 root, the 2 middle in the left subtree, and the 1 and the 4 in the right subtree is a better assignment.

And also based on one of Eric's deleted comments that has since been deleted, but the gist of it is in their answer. Basically:

- If a person has at least one child and *any* of the children do not have a phone, then the person needs a phone so that any of the children without a phone can borrow it.
- If a person has at least one child and *all* the children have a phone, then the person does not need a phone because they can borrow a phone from one of their children.
- A person with a parent and no children does not need a phone because they can borrow a phone from their parent.
- A person with no parent and no children needs a phone because they cannot borrow a phone from anyone. (This is the case when the tree contains only one person.)

The code uses a running counter that gets incremented by the recursive function, and includes a testing framework to exercise the code using a command line argument to specify the binary tree.

**minphones.c**

```
struct TreeNode
{
    struct TreeNode* left;
    struct TreeNode* right;
};

/* Returns 1 if the node's parent definitely needs a phone, else returns 0. */
static int needPhone(struct TreeNode *node, int *count)
{
    if (!node)
    {
        /* Not a node, so the parent might not need a phone. */
        return 0;
    }
    else if (needPhone(node->left, count) | needPhone(node->right, count))
    {
        /*
         * This node definitely requires a phone because there is at least
         * one child that needs to borrow a phone.
         *
         * Increment the count of phones.
         *
         * (Could optionally mark the node as possessing a phone.)
         */
        (*count)++;
        /*
         * This node has a phone so the parent might not need a phone
         * because they can borrow one from this node.
         */
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * This node either has no children, or all the children have a 
         * phone, so this node does not need a phone, but the parent definitely
         * needs a phone.
         */
        return 1;
    }

}

int minPhones(struct TreeNode *root)
{
    int count = 0;

    if (needPhone(root, &count))
    {
        /*
         * The root node (if any) reports that it needs to borrow a phone
         * from its parent, but because the root node does not have a
         * parent, it needs its own phone.
         *
         * (Could optionally mark the root node as possessing a phone.)
         */
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

/* Test */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct TreeNode *createNode(void)
{
    struct TreeNode *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

const char *createTree_(struct TreeNode **node, const char *desc, int *err)
{
    if (*desc == '[')
    {
        *node = createNode();
        desc = createTree_(&(*node)->left, desc + 1, err);
        if (*desc == ',')
        {
            desc = createTree_(&(*node)->right, desc + 1, err);
        }
        if (*desc == ']')
        {
            desc = desc + 1;
        }
        else if (*desc == '\0')
        {
            *err = 1;
        }
    }
    return desc;
}

struct TreeNode *createTree(const char *desc)
{
    struct TreeNode *root = NULL;
    int premature_end = 0;
    const char *remainder = createTree_(&root, desc, &premature_end);

    if (*remainder != '\0')
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Excess characters: %s\n", remainder);
    }
    else if (premature_end)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Premature end of description\n");
    }
    return root;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct TreeNode *root;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "usage: %s TREEDESC\n"
                "\n"
                "TREEDESC is a sequence of '[', ',', ']' characters forming a binary tree.\n"
                "For example: [[],[,[]]] represents the tree:\n"
                "\n"
                "     X\n"
                "    / \\\n"
                "   X   X\n"
                "        \\\n"
                "         X\n",
                argv[0]);
        exit(2);
    }
    root = createTree(argv[1]);
    printf("Minimum phones required = %d\n", minPhones(root));
    return 0;
}
```

Example testing session:

```shell
$ ./minphones
usage: ./minphones TREEDESC

TREEDESC is a sequence of '[', ',', ']' characters forming a binary tree.
For example: [[],[,[]]] represents the tree:

     X
    / \
   X   X
        \
         X
$ ./minphones ""
Minimum phones required = 0
$ ./minphones []
Minimum phones required = 1
$ ./minphones [[],]
Minimum phones required = 1
$ ./minphones [,[]]
Minimum phones required = 1
$ ./minphones [[],[,[]]]
Minimum phones required = 2
$ ./minphones [[[[],[]],[[],[]]],[[[[],[]],[[],[]]],[[[],[]],[[],[]]]]]
Minimum phones required = 8
```